# JS to change image/video src if server unreachable

Tags: javascript, html, firewall

Question:  I am interested in a small javascript code that checks if the user has access to Smugmug.com, and if *not* changes the image source to a different server (plan to implement this with video, but this example is with images only).  There will be one Smugmug check, multiple Source changes on the same html page.  [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk2Kt/10/) I have put together to test this out.  When I change `smugmug.com/favicon.ico` to `smug1234mug.com/favicon.ico` the code *does not* change the source image.

HTML:

```
<body>

<img id="myImage1" onload="changeImage('myImage1','http://www.prometeogallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Invitation_NO_GLOBALTOUR-800x575.jpg')" src="http://www.americanrestomods.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/logo-portfolio-smugmug.png" width="100" height="100">
</body>
```

JS:

```
// check if SmugMug is reachable (run once only)
var isSmugMug = "1";

var SMimage = new Image();
SMimage.onload = function(){
    window.isSmugMug = "1";
// The user can access SmugMug
};
SMimage.onerror = function(){
// The user can't access SmugMug
    window.isSmugMug = "0";
};
SMimage.src = "http://smugmug.com/favicon.ico";


function changeImage(p1,p2) {

    if (window.isSmugMug===0) {
        document.getElementById(p1).src=p2;
    }

}
```

Comment: The above looks close enough. What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work.  When I change the smugmug favicon address to something that is clearly not present, there is no affect on the image src.  It doesn't load my secondary link http://www.prometeogallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Invitation_NO_GLOBALTOUR-800x575.jpg

Comment: I just noticed `window.isSmugMug===0` will never be true since `window.isSmugMug` is always set to a string and not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you've 2 problems. The first is a minor issue regarding the use of the triple equals (`===`), the triple equals operator checks not only the values equality but the type equality.

Since you use strings in the value declaration, onload and onerror functions, and a number in the if statement, the condition will never be true, because `"1"===1` is false. You can either change your condition to a string or just use a normal double equals.

The second problem you have is a bit more complicated, and it's due to the timing of the various events being triggered, the code you've written will only work if the events are fired in a particular order, the `changeImage` function relies on `isSmugMug` being set appropriately when it is called, if `changeImage` is called before the `SMimage` loads (or doesn't) `isSmugMug` will still be your default value of `1`

Here's an example of a solution to your second problem:

```
// check if SmugMug is reachable (run once only)
var isSmugMug = "1";
var smugMugChecked = false;

var SMimage = new Image();
SMimage.onload = function(){
    window.isSmugMug = "1";
    smugMugChecked = true;
// The user can access SmugMug
};
SMimage.onerror = function(){
// The user can't access SmugMug
    window.isSmugMug = "0";
    smugMugChecked = true;
};
SMimage.src = "http://smugmug.com/favicon.ico";


function changeImage(p1,p2) {
    var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (smugMugChecked == true) {
            clearInterval(checkInterval);
            if (window.isSmugMug==0) {
                document.getElementById(p1).src=p2;
            }
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Here, I've added a variable to hold the state of whether the `SMimage` check has completed or not, the `changeImage` uses a 500 millisecond interval timer to wait for the `SMimage` check to complete, after the check is complete the timer is removed and the image is changed. This isn't a perfect solution, especially if you've got a lot of these checks on one page.

Comment: Works well.  I kinda thought that the JS would run first in <head> prior to the html onload.  And the delay is only 500ms for all images, not for each image.

Comment: Is there any way to force the load of the favicon/check before calling the change source function?